# Hibernate Lazy Loaded Entites Id

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Question, am currently using hibernate and I was wondering if there was any way to get the value of a lazy loaded entities id without hitting the DB again? For example we currently have an entity called group that has a `ManyToOne` relationship with another entity Organization.

when we call a simple repository method
`groupsRepository.findByUser(id)` it returns a list of groups based on given user. The query looks like this

```
select
    groups0_.PersonId as PersonId1_118_1_,
    groups0_.GroupId as GroupId2_8_1_,
    groups1_.GroupID as GroupID1_74_0_,
    groups1_.CreatedAt as CreatedA2_74_0_,
    groups1_.CreatedBy as CreatedB3_74_0_,
    groups1_.Description as Descript4_74_0_,
    groups1_.Name as Name5_74_0_,
    groups1_.OrganizationID as Organiza9_74_0_,
    groups1_.Role as Role6_74_0_,
    groups1_.Status as Status10_74_0_,
    groups1_.TouchedAt as TouchedA7_74_0_,
    groups1_.TouchedBy as TouchedB8_74_0_ 
from
    Groupsofpeople groups0_ 
inner join
    groups groups1_ 
        on groups0_.GroupId=groups1_.GroupID 
where
    groups0_.PersonId=?
```

Later on I need to see if the groups org is equal to another org which I do by comparing the OrganizaitonId's, a value that has already been fetched from the db. But every time I do this I have fetch the org from the db, is there anyway to prevent that so that the org attached to group will be prepopulated with it's id since it is already being fetched anyway?  Or is this just a concession I have to make if I am using hibernate?

Comment: can you provide your actual hibernate query?